# How to have a sticky header for a GridLayout in a Flickable

Tags: qt, qml

I have a GridLayout populated by a Repeater (a TableView doesn't fit my needs), inside a Flickable so I can scroll the content.

I want my GridLayout to have a header, which I can easily by adding `Text`s before my Repeater like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

ColumnLayout {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Flickable {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredHeight: 200
        contentWidth: width
        contentHeight: grid.height
        clip: true

        GridLayout {
            id: grid
            columns: 3
            columnSpacing: 10

            function reparentChildren(source, target) {
                while (source.children.length) {
                    source.children[0].parent = target;
                }
            }

            // Header
            Text {
                text: "Header 0"
            }
            Text {
                text: "Header 1"
            }
            Text {
                text: "Header 2"
            }

            // Data
            Repeater {
                model: 50

                Item {
                    Component.onCompleted: grid.reparentChildren(this, grid)
                    Text {
                        text: "Column 0, %1".arg(modelData)
                    }
                    Text {
                        text: "Column 1, %1".arg(modelData)
                    }
                    Text {
                        text: "Column 2, %1".arg(modelData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I would like my header to be "sticky" / "frozen", i.e. remain visible when scrolling the Flickable.
I could create my header outside the Flickable, however the GridLayout doesn't give me the final row sizes, so I cannot position my header texts.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but I found a solution.

First, create "dummy" headers which are `Item`s. You can make set their `Layout.minimalWidth` to be the width of the header text if you need to.

Then, in a Item before the Flickable, create your header, make sure it is horizontally aligned with the grid, and position the elements using the `x` values of the header.

Finally, set a negative margin on the Flickable to remove the extraneous row added by the dummy headers.

I also tried using `fillWidth: true` on the dummies and then setting the `width` of each header items, but the downside is that it modifies the table column width.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

ColumnLayout {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    // Header
    Item {
        Layout.minimumHeight: childrenRect.height
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Text {
            id: header0
            x: headerDummy0.x
            anchors.top: parent.top
            text: "Header 0"
        }
        Text {
            id: header1
            x: headerDummy1.x
            anchors.top: parent.top
            text: "Header 1"
        }
        Text {
            id: header2
            x: headerDummy2.x
            anchors.top: parent.top
            text: "Header 2"
        }
    }

    Flickable {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredHeight: 200
        contentWidth: width
        contentHeight: grid.height
        clip: true
        // Eliminate the first row, which are the dummies
        topMargin: - grid.rowSpacing

        GridLayout {
            id: grid
            columns: 3
            rowSpacing: 50
            columnSpacing: 10

            function reparentChildren(source, target) {
                while (source.children.length) {
                    source.children[0].parent = target;
                }
            }

            // Header dummies
            Item {
                id: headerDummy0
                Layout.minimumWidth: header0.implicitWidth
            }
            Item {
                id: headerDummy1
                Layout.minimumWidth: header1.implicitWidth
            }
            Item {
                id: headerDummy2
                Layout.minimumWidth: header2.implicitWidth
            }

            // Data
            Repeater {
                model: 50

                Item {
                    Component.onCompleted: grid.reparentChildren(this, grid)
                    Text {
                        text: "Column 0, %1".arg(modelData)
                    }
                    Text {
                        text: "Column 1, %1".arg(modelData)
                    }
                    Text {
                        text: "Column 2, %1".arg(modelData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```